# Salesforce Inbound Email issue/not working

Tags: apex, inboundemail

I wrote an Apex class for inbound email to update records, but I can't get it to work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but sending an email doesn't update anything.

The email sent to Email services are rich text but the only two things needed are the first Paid and Sent fields mentioned in the email.

Subject of the email looks like: "RE: Update Numbers for Bill 001 a1X01000004dY7"

Here's my code:

```
global class BillEmailParser2 implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

    //Parse the email body and subject
    String subject = email.subject, body = email.plainTextBody;
    
    //Check if the email subject contains "RE: Update Numbers"
    if (subject.contains('RE: Update Numbers')) {
        //Look for specific words in the body
        if (body.contains('Bill Paid on')) {
        //Extract the Bill Paid On
        Integer startIndex = body.indexOf('Bill Paid On') + 'Bill Paid On:'.length();
        Integer endIndex = body.indexOf('\n', startIndex);
        if (endIndex == -1) {
            endIndex = body.length();
        }
        String billPaidOnStr = body.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim();
        Date billPaidOn = Date.valueOf(billPaidOnStr);
        
        //Extract the Bill Sent On 
        startIndex = body.indexOf('Bill Sent On') + 'Bill Sent On:'.length();
        endIndex = body.indexOf('\n', startIndex);
        if (endIndex == -1) {
            endIndex = body.length();
        }
        String billSentOnStr = body.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim();
        Date billSentOn = Date.valueOf(billSentOnStr);
            
            //Extract the Billing__c ID from subject
            String billId = email.Subject.substring(email.Subject.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
            
            //Look up the bill by ID
            Billing__c b = [SELECT Id, Bill_Paid_On__c, Bill_Sent_On__c FROM Billing__c WHERE Id = :billId];
            
            //Update the bill with the due date information
            if (b != null) {
                b.Bill_Paid_On__c = billPaidOn;
                b.Bill_Sent_On__c = billSentOn;
                update b;
            }
        }
    }
    result.success = true;
    return result;

}}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what "I can't get it to work" means. If you're running into an error, you should include the full text of the error, verbatim (paraphrasing errors usually means you'll leave out important information). If you haven't looked at a debug log yet, that's the first place you should look. I can't recall if you can set a running user for that, or if the debug logs would fall under the "Automated Process User" (which you would specifically need to set up a debug trace flag for).

Comment: I do not see any error. Downloaded the email logs and it shows that the emails were received by the server. By default I am the user.

Deployed the email service with this apex class but I don't see any error on either the class or the email services and this class doesn't update the records with dates mentioned in email body. That is why I am stumped as I have no idea where to go from here. 

Not sure if it this matters but the Date format in body is as 'Paid on: 6/18/2022'

Comment: bu you're looking for 'Bill Paid On'

Comment: @NickCook I am. I left Bill in the comment

Comment: note that `contains` is a case sensitive compare so check your input data

Answer (score 0):

your method *handleInboundEmail* does not return anything, you should add a ***return result;*** at the end, since at the beginning of your method you have Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

Comment: Yikes, I had it under my code but didn't paste it here. I will update my code above.
Still this doesn't work.

Comment: Ok if you add some system.debugs() and then send an email with a debug log open, do you see any system.debug being outputted in the log ?